# write function in Fortran

Tags: printing, gfortran

The following program works fine with "print" but when I try to use "write", the gfortran compiler on my Ubuntu produces the following run-time error:

[image: Error Screen]

```
! What is the sum of the largest and lowest three-digit numbers that can
! exactly be divided by 9 and yield the remainder of 3 when they divide
! any xyz4 number? (Answer: 1116)
program divide_remain
implicit none
integer :: xyz4,abc,i=0  ! abc is a 3-digit number
integer, allocatable :: sayi(:) ! an array holding possible abc numbers

allocate(sayi(i))

do xyz4=1004,9994,10
   do abc=108,999,9
      if(MOD(xyz4,abc)==3) then
         i=i+1
         sayi(i)=abc
       endif
   enddo
enddo

!print*,'The lowest 3-digit number=',MINVAL(sayi(1:i))
!print*,'The largest 3-digit number=',MAXVAL(sayi(1:i))
!print*,'Sum of these numbers=',MINVAL(sayi(1:i))+MAXVAL(sayi(1:i))

write(6,10)'The lowest 3-digit number=',MINVAL(sayi(1:i))
write(6,10)'The largest 3-digit number=',MINVAL(sayi(1:i))
write(6,11)'Sum of these numbers=',MINVAL(sayi(1:i))+MAXVAL(sayi(1:i))

10 format(a,i3)
11 format(a,i4)

deallocate(sayi)

end program divide_remain
```

Comment: Wat is the size of sayi? I see the statements: say(i)=abc with and i > 0 and before this allocate(sayi(i)) done with i=0.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I thought it would be enough to initialize i=0 on the third line from top. Do I need to type it just before the "allocate(sayi(i))" command?

Comment: The size of the array sayi, the last value of i, is 85.

Comment: Before accessing an array element the array should be allocated to (minimal) the right size. For your example the value of 85 would do, but for other problems the number might / will be different.

Comment: Thank you very much. I did not know this. Following your correction, I changed the allocation line as "allocate(sayi(85))", and it worked just fine. Best regards.
http://i1038.photobucket.com/albums/a470/hdbalzac/Questions%20and-or%20Solutions/code.gif